# How to get last three months' data in single query

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a query which gives the Sales value of last three months. I want to get all three months data in a single query instead of three different queries. If I give 'Mar-2016' it should display me last three months data Feb-2016 , Jan-2016 and Dec-2015.

Please help me with this.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE , 'MON-YYYY') S_MON , NULL T_MON, 
    TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE,'MM-YYYY') MM, C.SECTION_CODE SECTION,  
    B.ITEM_CODE ITEM_CODE, SUM(B.MASTER_QUANTITY) SALES,
    NULL TARGET
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_MASTER A, TRANSACTION_DETAIL B, 
    ITEM_SECTION C, ITEM D
WHERE 
    A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER = B.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
    AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.JOB_DATE,1), 'MON-YYYY') = 'MAR-2016'
    AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE = B.TRANSACTION_CODE
    AND B.ITEM_CODE  = D.ITEM_CODE
    AND C.SECTION_CODE = D.SECTION_CODE
    AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE IN (2,4)
    AND D.ITEM_STATUS = 'A'
    AND C.SECTION_CODE BETWEEN :ST_CODE AND :END_CODE 
GROUP BY  
    TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE, 'MON-YYYY'), TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE, 'MM-YYYY'),
    C.SECTION_CODE, B.ITEM_CODE 

UNION

SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') S_MON, NULL T_MON,  
    TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') MM, 
    C.SECTION_CODE SECTION, B.ITEM_CODE ITEM_CODE, 
    SUM(B.MASTER_QUANTITY ) SALES, NULL TARGET
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_MASTER A, TRANSACTION_DETAIL B, 
    ITEM_SECTION C, ITEM D
WHERE 
    A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER = B.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
    AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.JOB_DATE, 2), 'MON-YYYY')= 'MAR-2016'
  AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE = B.TRANSACTION_CODE
  AND B.ITEM_CODE  = D.ITEM_CODE
  AND C.SECTION_CODE = D.SECTION_CODE
  AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE IN (2,4)
  AND D.ITEM_STATUS = 'A'
  AND C.SECTION_CODE BETWEEN :ST_CODE AND :END_CODE 


  GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE , 'MON-YYYY') , TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE,'MM-YYYY') ,C.SECTION_CODE  ,  B.ITEM_CODE 


  UNION  

  SELECT TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE , 'MON-YYYY') S_MON , NULL T_MON , TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE,'MM-YYYY') MM , 
  C.SECTION_CODE SECTION ,  B.ITEM_CODE ITEM_CODE , SUM(B.MASTER_QUANTITY ) SALES , NULL TARGET

  FROM TRANSACTION_MASTER A  , TRANSACTION_DETAIL B  , ITEM_SECTION C , ITEM D

  WHERE A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER = B.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
  AND  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.JOB_DATE,3),'MON-YYYY') = 'MAR-2016'
  AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE = B.TRANSACTION_CODE
  AND B.ITEM_CODE  = D.ITEM_CODE
  AND C.SECTION_CODE = D.SECTION_CODE
  AND A.TRANSACTION_CODE IN (2,4)
  AND D.ITEM_STATUS = 'A'
  AND C.SECTION_CODE BETWEEN :ST_CODE AND :END_CODE 

   GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE , 'MON-YYYY') , TO_CHAR(A.JOB_DATE,'MM-YYYY') ,C.SECTION_CODE  ,  B.ITEM_CODE
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only thing which is different in the union-ed sub-queries is this line of the WHERE clause:

```
AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.JOB_DATE,1), 'MON-YYYY') = 'MAR-2016'
                                  ^
```

The actual logic you are applying is this **(*)**:

```
and a.job_date between date '2015-12-01' and date '2016-02-29'
```

This can be generalized with a parameter to

```
and a.job_date between :p_start_date and last_day(add_months(:p_start_date,2))
```

If the number of months in the date range is also variable then you need another parameter.

and a.job_date between :p_start_date and last_day(add_months(:p_start_date,:p_add_months_int))

The `p_add_months_int` value is one less than the number of months in the range: so `2` bounds a range of three of months.

If you want to define the range for the last three months by passing in the end date then use negative numbers in the `add_months()` call:

```
and a.job_date between trunc(add_months(:p_end_date,-2)) and last_day(:p_end_date)
```

---

> " if i give 'Mar-2016' it should display me last 3 months data Feb-2016 , Jan-2016 and Dec-2015."

Okay, for precisely that, what you want is

```
and a.job_date between add_months(to_date(:p_start_date, 'MON-YYYY'),-3)) 
              and to_date(:p_start_date, 'MON-YYYY'),-1)
```

---

**(*)** If you expecting a date range of 2016-01-01 to 2016-03-31 you may have misunderstood what `ADD_MONTHS(A.JOB_DATE,1)` does.

Comment: Well i have decided to specify only one parameter i.e., if i give 'Mar-2016' it should display me last 3 months data Feb-2016 , Jan-2016 and Dec-2015. This is what i want.

Comment: Thats what I wanted . Thank you so much..!!